# ArcObjects - Listen to Editor events in Extension Add-In using Java

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects

I'm struggling at finding a way to listen to Editor events in my extension add-in. What am I trying to do is: after user creates a new point feature, extension should populate an attribute of it with its Z value. So I guess my extension needs to be aware of `IEditEventsOnCreateFeatureEvent` dispatch, but I don't know how to handle it using ArcObjects for Java. Documentation and forums are full of suggestions using VB and C#, and for ArcGIS Engine, but no Java Extension Add-In AFAIK.

Everything I've been able to do until now is getting an `IEditor` reference (which is not much, I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer myself. I guess it can help many other users as well.

Maybe my code is self-explanatory. Remember: it is an ArcObjects Extension Add-In code (Java). See below (with comments):

```
public class AutoCotar extends Extension {

private Editor m_editor; // IMPORTANT - Use Editor, not IEditor, as the latter does not
                         // have the method addIEditEventsListener!
public IMxDocument mxDoc;

@Override
public void init(IApplication app) throws IOException, AutomationException {
    mxDoc = (IMxDocument) app.getDocument();

    // Get the Editor Extension reference
    IUID extensionID = new UID();
    extensionID.setValue("esriEditor.Editor");
    IExtension editExtension = app.findExtensionByCLSID(extensionID);
    m_editor = (Editor) editExtension;

    // THE TRICK - Create a new IEditEventsAdapter and add it to m_editor
    m_editor.addIEditEventsListener(new IEditEventsAdapter(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // Now all you need to do is implement the behaviour
        // of the events you want to deal with!

        public void onCreateFeature(IEditEventsOnCreateFeatureEvent arg0) throws IOException, AutomationException {
            IFeature theFeature = (IFeature) arg0.getObj();
            int atribCota = theFeature.getFields().findField("cota");
            if(atribCota >= 0)
            {
                IGeometry theGeom = theFeature.getShape();
                theFeature.setValue(atribCota, theGeom.getEnvelope().getZMax());
                theFeature.store();

                mxDoc.getActiveView().partialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null, theFeature.getExtent());
            }
        }

        public void onChangeFeature(IEditEventsOnChangeFeatureEvent arg0) throws IOException, AutomationException {
            this.onCreateFeature(new IEditEventsOnCreateFeatureEvent(arg0.getObj()));
        }
    });
}
```

}